# Python: Read only file name, instead of path

Tags: python, path, filenames

How to get ONLY filename instead of full path?

For example:

```
path = /folder/file.txt
```

and i need to get:

```
filename = file.txt
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `os` module:

```
import os
filename = os.path.basename(path)
```

For other path manipulations look [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) (for python 2.7) or [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) (for python 3)